# I am not able to implement Twilio to send SMS on WordPress using wp_remote_post

Tags: wordpress, twilio

How can I use wp_remote_post to send SMS from Twilio?
The code below work nice, but it need to be done with WordPress HTTP API using wp_remote_post

```
function send_twilio_text_msg($id, $token, $from, $to, $body)
{

$url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/".$id."/SMS/Messages";
$data = array (
  'From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Body' => $body,
);
  $post = http_build_query($data);
  $x = curl_init($url );
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$id:$token");
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
  $y = curl_exec($x);
  curl_close($x);
  print_r($y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a call to the Twilio API using `wp_remote_post` you need to do a few things:

1. Create the URL, as you did in your example
2. Collect the data you want to send (your `From`, `To`, and `Body` from your example)
3. Create an `Authorization` header out of your Account Sid and Auth Token. To do so, you need an array with one key, `Authorization` and the value made from base 64 encoding the Account Sid and Auth Token concatenated with a colon.
4. The `$url` is the first argument to `wp_remote_post` the second argument is an associative array with  `body` and `headers` properties.

See the example below:

```
function send_twilio_text_msg($id, $token, $from, $to, $body)
{
  $url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/".$id."/SMS/Messages";
  $data = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Body' => $body
  );
  $headers = array(
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($id . ':' . $token)
  );
  $result = wp_remote_post($url, array(
    'body' => $data,
    'headers' => $headers
  ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Well, I already know that.  But where is the token? In my code, I have pass token in this way - 

curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$id:$token");

Comment: ah got it. have you tried passing it in as part of your data array? You'd also need to specify some headers. Take a look at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/205444/how-can-i-use-curlopt-userpwd-in-wp-remote-post and let me know if that works or gives an error?

Comment: Just edited this answer. Looks like we need an array with a `body` that contains the request data and [`headers` that include the basic auth](https://johnblackbourn.com/wordpress-http-api-basicauth/) with the accound sid and auth token.